# How to compile the freetype module of opencv_contrib for android

Tags: android, opencv, cmake, cross-compiling, ndk-build

opencv provides a method called putText that can't handle custom fonts, and then discovers the freetype wrapper module in opencv_contrib.
I tried to compile opencv4android and opencv_contrib

```
python3 $HOME/opencv-4.8.0/platforms/android/build_sdk.py --debug_info --no_samples_build --no_ccache --config=$HOME/opencv-4.8.0/platforms/android/ndk-25.config.py --sdk_path=$HOME/sdk --extra_modules_path $HOME/opencv_contrib/modules  $HOME/build_android
```

However, the compiled result does not have a freetype
how can i compile the freetype module to opencv4Android?

Later I learned that this was because the dependency packages freetype and harfbuzz required special handling in a cross-compile environment, but I didn't know what to do with it.

Then I tried to cross-compile freetype and harfbuzz separately,

```
cmake -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=/home/vagrant/android-ndk-r26/build/cmake/and roid.toolchain.cmake -DANDROID_ABI=arm64-v8a -DANDROID_NATIVE_API_LEVEL=29  -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/lo cal/arm64/freetype  /home/vagrant/freetype-2.10.0
```

```
cmake -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=/home/vagrant/android-ndk-r26/build/cmake/and roid.toolchain.cmake -DANDROID_ABI=arm64-v8a -DANDROID_NATIVE_API_LEVEL=29 -DHB_HAVE_FREETYPE=ON -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local/arm64/harfbuzz  /home/vagrant/harfbuzz-8.1.0
```

The compiler cannot find freetype, which I have compiled separately

Then, I tried manually setting up the CMakeLists.txt for harfbuzz, but I don't know if this is correct

```
  set(FREETYPE_LIBRARIES /usr/local/arm64/freetype/lib/libfreetype.a)
  set(FREETYPE_INCLUDE_DIRS /usr/local/arm64/freetype/include/freetype2)
```

After cross-compiling freeypte and harfbuzz, I tried to compile opencv and opencv_contrib, and set up the freetype wrapper in opencv_contrib After compiling the freetype and harfbuzz LIBRARIES and INCLUDE_DIRS, I used them in my ndk project. Can't find the package when the NDK - build/usr/local/arm64 freetype/lib/libfreetype.a, / usr/local/arm64/harfbuzz/lib/libharfbuzz.a

Should I cross-compile opencv_contrib freetype if correct?